# Creating a cut off for a slide animation in CSS?

Tags: html, css, overflow, hidden, slide

I've tried approaching this situation from multiple angles, but since I seem to be coming up short, I feel like getting a second perspective would help me.

This is probably a VERY simple question, but I for the life of me cannot figure it out, nor find an answer.

In short, I'm making a recreation website (basing it off an old flash site). There's an image that slides down and then gets cut off, and I have no clue how to do the cut off section.

[Here is a photo illustrating that I've created a div with a 553x553px radius with an overflow:hidden tag but the image still appears outside the perimeters.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJ5Gl.png)

Here is the code for the divs and slide animation (it starts in the middle of the box then is suppose to slide down, cutting off half the image when it's finished):

```
.flex {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
height: 775px;
}

.ctr {
display: absolute;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
height: 553px;
width: 553px;
overflow: hidden;
}

#slide {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100px;
    width: 552px;
    height: 343px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url('Intro/3.png');
    -webkit-animation: slide 1s forwards;
    animation: slide 1s forwards;
    animation-delay: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
    }

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
    100% { bottom: 0; }
}

@keyframes slide {
    100% { bottom: 0; }
}
```

I don't feel like these are important to the problem, but since they're in the code, just to cover all my basis, here they are:

```
.bg {
    position: absolute;
    width: 795px;
    left: 50%
    margin-left: -300px;
    }

.center {
    height: 585px;
    position: absolute;
    }
```

And here is the code itself:

```
<body style="background-color:#421111;">
<div class = "flex">
  <img src="bg.png" class="center"> 
  <div class = "ctr">
  <p id = "slide"></p>
  </div>
  <img src="108.png" class="bg"> 
</div>
```

(Just for clarity, "bg.png" is the purple inside, 108.png is the frame outline)

[This is what I'm trying to achieve, based off the old site.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqw1G.png)

I know my image isn't far down enough compared to the original site, but I'm trying to fix this issue first. In any case, I'm simply wracking my brain here, since I don't understand how I can create a cutoff. I thought using overflow:hidden; would work, but it doesn't seem to...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where have you tried the overflow hidden? Also it would be really helpful if you could include enough code (that means relevant image too) as a runnable snippet. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the image you are trying to cut off is outside of the div with the class="ctr".
This should fix your problem:

```
<body style="background-color:#421111;">
<div class = "flex">
   <div class = "ctr">
      <img src="bg.png" class="center"> 
      <p id = "slide"></p>
   </div>
<img src="108.png" class="bg"> 
</div>
```

An alternative would be to use either clip-path or a mask but I really wouldn´t recommend this.

However if you use these (clip-path or mask), make sure to apply it directly to the image itself.

If that also doesn´t work e.g. you don´t have browser support for this, try and do it with an animation or transition. An Example:

```
<style>
[cut]{
   transition: width 1s, height 1s;
   width: 600px;
   height: 600px;
}
[cut]:hover{
   transition: width 1s, height 1s;
   width: 553px;
   height: 553px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply!! The image I'm trying to get cut-off is actually the background within the #slide animation - Intro/3.png (background-image: url('Intro/3.png');). Bg.png is the purple background. Sorry for the confusion!!